# How do i represent a String object/variable as an array variable name in java?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, switch-statement

I have a function with one argument in it of type int and it includes the position, and I have to return an array matching to that position. E.G. position = 3 I have to return array arr4.

Ok simple I can use a switch statement to easily handle this situation, but the thing is there are a total of 1000 arrays and which all will be called once in a run time, so writing switch will a crazy idea

```
 public String Convert(String s, int position) {
        //s=s.toLowerCase();
        String result = "";
        String array[]=null;
        String array2[]=null;
        String array3[]=null;
        String space = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                array = arr1;
                array2 = arr1a;
                array3 = arr1b;
                space = arr1c;
                break;

            case 1:
                array = arr2;
                array2 = arr2a;
                array3 = arr2b;
                space = arr2c;
                break; 
....
```

so I tried something like this to overcome this problem

```
 array = "arr"+1;
```

but it didn't work as I thought and I don't know can I cast a string into an array name or something else.

IS THERE ANY SOLUTION TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM.

Comment: You can use a HashMap<String,Integer[]> where the key is array name you want to return and the value is the array itself. You can't cast a string into any type besides string

Comment: Or you can use a two-dimensional array, where each row is a single-dimensional array. For example, it could be declared as ``int[3][] arrays;``, assuming you have three arrays.